# How to apply to an object the same position and scaling of another object in Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a Fabric group loaded from a SVG tag.
When the SVG content changes, I would like to change the Fabric groupaccordingly.
Sadly if I just remove everything from the Fabric group and push back the SVG content, it resets the group position, scaling and transformations.

What are my options there?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jsbarcode/3.6.0/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<button id="change">Change barcode</button>
<div id="divBarcode">
 <svg id="svgBarcode"></svg>
</div>
<canvas id="fabric" width="500px" height="500px" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
<script>
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("fabric");
let barcode = undefined;
// Creates a barcode
JsBarcode("#svgBarcode", "Example 1234", {
 background: null,
 format: "CODE128"
});
// Removes the font style because fabric has parse errors
$("#svgBarcode text").attr("style", "");
// Adds the barcode in fabric
fabric.loadSVGFromString($("#divBarcode").html(), (objects, options) => {
 barcode = new fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
 canvas.add(barcode);
 canvas.requestRenderAll();
});
$("#change").click(e => {
 // We generate a new svg barcode
 JsBarcode("#svgBarcode", "New one", {
  background: null,
  format: "CODE128"
 });
 $("#svgBarcode text").attr("style", "");
 // Now here is the tricky part, I need to change it in fabric too
 fabric.loadSVGFromString($("#divBarcode").html(), (objects, options) => {
  barcode.getObjects().forEach(obj => barcode.remove(obj));
  objects.forEach(obj => barcode.addWithUpdate(obj));
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
  // But it resets the position and scaling
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can try to save the position, scaling and transformation before replacing the fabric group

Comment: I did, I did copy all the propreties except the ones starting by an underscore from the old group to the new one and it did work kinda for the position but not the scaling and transformation

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Yes, not right now because it's 7am and I need to sleep but I will tomorrow

Comment: I just added a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need somethink like this?

```js
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("fabric");
let barcode = undefined;
// Creates a barcode
JsBarcode("#svgBarcode", "Example 1234", {
 background: null,
 format: "CODE128"
});
// Removes the font style because fabric has parse errors
$("#svgBarcode text").attr("style", "");
// Adds the barcode in fabric
fabric.loadSVGFromString($("#divBarcode").html(), (objects, options) => {
 barcode = new fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
 canvas.add(barcode);
 canvas.requestRenderAll();
});
$("#change").click(e => {
 // We generate a new svg barcode
 JsBarcode("#svgBarcode", "New one", {
  background: null,
  format: "CODE128"
 });
 $("#svgBarcode text").attr("style", "");
  var originalTransfomation = {
   left:canvas.getObjects()[0].left,
   top:canvas.getObjects()[0].top,
   width:canvas.getObjects()[0].width,
   height:canvas.getObjects()[0].height,
    skewY:canvas.getObjects()[0].skewY,
       skewX:canvas.getObjects()[0].skewX,
   scaleX:canvas.getObjects()[0].scaleX,
   scaleY:canvas.getObjects()[0].scaleY,
   angle:canvas.getObjects()[0].angle
  }
 // Now here is the tricky part, I need to change it in fabric too
 fabric.loadSVGFromString($("#divBarcode").html(), (objects, options) => {
  barcode.getObjects().forEach(obj => barcode.remove(obj));
  objects.forEach(obj => barcode.addWithUpdate(obj));
    barcode.left = originalTransfomation.left;
     barcode.top = originalTransfomation.top;
      barcode.width = originalTransfomation.width;
        barcode.height = originalTransfomation.height;
        barcode.scaleY = originalTransfomation.scaleY;
        barcode.scaleX = originalTransfomation.scaleX;
         barcode.angle = originalTransfomation.angle;
         barcode.skewX= originalTransfomation.skewX;
         barcode.skewY= originalTransfomation.skewY;
         barcode.setCoords();
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
  // But it resets the position and scaling
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jsbarcode/3.6.0/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<button id="change">Change barcode</button>
<div id="divBarcode">
 <svg id="svgBarcode"></svg>
</div>
<canvas id="fabric" width="500px" height="500px" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you it works like a charm! The only issue now is that it resets the transformation when you use shift (I'm not sure how to explain what I mean so here is a screenshot https://gyazo.com/a5317f26ef5321bb257c52ec1cc901d2 )

Comment: Thank you so much, you're amazing!